# Access Local VB Dll using <object>

Tags: javascript, vb6, object-tag

Can I access a Local registered Dll like this

```
 <object classid="clsid:8fa8600b-dd9d-4ec2-a533-2986cb0df433" id="dllId">
    </object>
```

from javascript like this:

```
  function dllData(){
        alert('called')
        var objData = document.getElementById('dllId');
        alert(objData);
   }
```

Am trying to do this from a normal HTML page. Is it possible in the above manner?

Kindly suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No. You'll need to instantiate objects from that DLL via "new ActiveXObject()", then call methods off that object instance.

Comment: Thanks david, but it will force me to use only IE..any other options to work on various browsers?

Comment: VB6 DLL's are COM  Automation servers, and as such the only way I know to leverage them is by instantiating objects within them in this way. To my knowledge, other browsers don't formally support Automation controllers (without some kind of plug in or comparable tool.